# Como crear un ID unico de reserva que no cambie al mostrar o modificar en JAVA

Tags: java, poo, netbeans, java-swing, java-8

Verán tengo terminado casi por completo un proyecto que me solicitaron del estudio.

Consiste en un restaurante que genere la reserva y este genere un ID único de reserva y que no cambie al mostrarlo, pero no se como hacerlo. Este incluye ya para modificar, eliminar o buscar por fecha pero no se como integrarlo en mi código.

**He logrado incluirlo pero este se cambia al volver mostrar la información o buscar esta reserva. Alguna quía o Tip de como integrarlo???**

**Clase CLIENTE**:

```
package restaurante;

   

/**
*
* @author Jeisson
*/
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.UUID;


/**
*
* @author Jeisson
*/
public class Cliente {
   private String identificacion;
   private String nombre;
   private String email;
   private String celular;
   private int cantidad;
   private String estado;
   private String motivo;
   private String decoracion;
   private String fecha;



   /**
    * Constructor
    */
   public Cliente()    {
       // Inicialización
       identificacion = "desconocido";
       nombre = "desconocido";
       email = "desconocido";
       celular = "desconocido";
       cantidad = 0;
       estado = "desconocido";
       motivo = "desconocido";
       decoracion = "desconocido";
       fecha = "desconocido";
   
       
     
   
   }

   //Metodos Modificadores//
   public void SetIdentificacion(String identificacion) {this.identificacion = identificacion;   }
   public void SetNombre(String nombre) {this.nombre = nombre; }
   public void SetEmail(String email) { this.email = email; }
   public void SetCelular(String celular) {this.celular = celular; }
   public void SetCantidad(int cantidad) {this.cantidad = cantidad; }
   public void SetEstado(String estado) {this.estado = estado; }
   public void SetMotivo(String motivo) {this.motivo = motivo; }
   public void SetDecoracion(String decoracion) {this.decoracion = decoracion; }
   public void SetFecha(String fecha) {this.fecha = fecha;}
 

   
  

   // Metodos Analizador//
   public String getIdentificacion() {return identificacion; }
   public String getNombre() {return nombre; }
   public String getEmail() {return email; }
   public String getCelular() { return celular;}
   public int getCantidad() {return cantidad;}
   public String getEstado() {return estado;}
   public String getMotivo() {return motivo;}
   public String getDecoracion() {return decoracion;}
   public String getFecha() {return fecha;}
 

   

 


    
    
   
   public String getStringCliente () {
       
       String mensaje = "Información actual del cliente: \n";
       mensaje = mensaje + "Identificacion: " + this.getIdentificacion()+"\n";
       mensaje = mensaje + "Nombre: " + this.getNombre()+"\n";
       mensaje = mensaje + "Fecha: " + this.getFecha() + "\n";
       mensaje = mensaje + "e-mail: " + this.getEmail() + "\n";
       mensaje = mensaje + "Celular: " + this.getCelular() + "\n";
       mensaje = mensaje + "Cant. de personas para la mesa: " + this.getCantidad() + "\n";
       mensaje = mensaje + "Estado: " + this.getEstado() + "\n";
       mensaje = mensaje + "Motivo: " + this.getMotivo() + "\n";
       mensaje = mensaje + "Tipo decoracion: " + this.getDecoracion() + "\n";
 
       
       
     
   
    
    
       mensaje = mensaje + "\n\n\n";
       return mensaje;
   }
   
     public String getBuscador() {
       
       String mensaje = "Información de reservas: \n";
       mensaje = mensaje + "Identificacion: " + this.getIdentificacion()+"\n";
       mensaje = mensaje + "Nombre: " + this.getNombre()+"\n";
       mensaje = mensaje + "Fecha: " + this.getFecha() + "\n";
       mensaje = mensaje + "Estado: " + this.getEstado() + "\n";

    
    
                    mensaje = mensaje + "\n\n\n";
       return mensaje;
   }
}
```

**CLASE DIALOGO**

```
package restaurante;

/**
 *
 * @author Jeisson
 */
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;


public class Dialogo {

    String dialogo;

    public Dialogo() {     }

    public int obtenerOpcionMenu() throws IOException {
        dialogo = "MENU DE  RESERVAS - LAS MARGARITAS\n";
        dialogo += "1.  Insertar Cliente\n";
        dialogo += "2.  Modificar Cliente\n";
        dialogo += "3.  Mostar  los Clientes\n";
        dialogo += "4.  Eliminar Cliente\n";
        dialogo += "5.  Buscar Reserva\n";
        dialogo += "6.  Salir\n";
        dialogo += "Escoja Opción:\n";
        return Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(dialogo));
    }

    public String obtenerIdentificacionCliente() throws IOException {
        dialogo = "Introduzca Identificacion del cliente\n";
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(dialogo);
    }
  

    //Completamos aquí la petición de datos
    public String obtenerNombreCliente() throws IOException {
        dialogo = "Introduzca Nombre del cliente\n";
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(dialogo);
    }

     public String obtenerCelularCliente() throws IOException {
        dialogo = "Introduzca Celular de pasajero\n";
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(dialogo);
    }
    
    public String obtenerFecha() throws IOException {
        dialogo = "Introduzca fecha de reserva\n";
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(dialogo);
    }
    
      public String obtenerEmailCliente() throws IOException {
        dialogo = "Introduzca email de pasajero\n";
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(dialogo);
    }
    
    
 
    public int obtenerCantidad() throws IOException {
        dialogo = "Introduzca Cant. de personas para la mesa\n";
        return Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(dialogo));
    }
    
    public String obtenerEstado() throws IOException {
        dialogo = "Introduzca el estado de reserva\n";
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(dialogo);
    }
    
    public String obtenerMotivo() throws IOException {
        dialogo = "Introduzca el motivo  de reserva\n";
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(dialogo);
    }
    
    public String obtenerTipodecoracion() throws IOException {
        dialogo = "Introduzca el tipo de decoracion de la mesa\n";
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(dialogo);
    }
      
    
   
    public void mostrarMensaje (String mensaje) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mensaje");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, mensaje);
    }
   
    public void cerrarPrograma () {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Final del programa");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Gracias por usar este programa. Fin");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

**CLASE MAIN**

```
package restaurante;

/**
 *
 * @author Jeisson
 */
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] Args) throws IOException {

        int opcionEligeUsuario = 0;
        List<Cliente> listaDeCliente = new ArrayList<>();
        Dialogo opcionesUsuario = new Dialogo();
        Dialogo mensajeVent = new Dialogo();

        while (opcionEligeUsuario != 6) {

            opcionEligeUsuario = opcionesUsuario.obtenerOpcionMenu();

            
            if (opcionEligeUsuario == 1) {

                Cliente tmpCliente = new Cliente();

                tmpCliente.SetIdentificacion(opcionesUsuario.obtenerIdentificacionCliente());
                tmpCliente.SetNombre(opcionesUsuario.obtenerNombreCliente());
                tmpCliente.SetEmail(opcionesUsuario.obtenerEmailCliente());
                tmpCliente.SetFecha(opcionesUsuario.obtenerFecha());
                tmpCliente.SetCelular(opcionesUsuario.obtenerCelularCliente());
                tmpCliente.SetCantidad(opcionesUsuario.obtenerCantidad());
                tmpCliente.SetEstado(opcionesUsuario.obtenerEstado());
                tmpCliente.SetMotivo(opcionesUsuario.obtenerMotivo());
                tmpCliente.SetDecoracion(opcionesUsuario.obtenerTipodecoracion());

                
                listaDeCliente.add(tmpCliente);
            }
            

            
            if (opcionEligeUsuario == 2) {
                String identClienteBuscado = opcionesUsuario.obtenerIdentificacionCliente();
                boolean clienteEncontrado = false;

                Iterator<Cliente> it = listaDeCliente.iterator();
                Cliente tmpAnalizando;

                while (it.hasNext()) {          

                    tmpAnalizando = it.next();               

                    if (tmpAnalizando.getIdentificacion().equals(identClienteBuscado)) {
                        clienteEncontrado = true;
                        String mensaje = tmpAnalizando.getStringCliente();
                        mensaje = mensaje + "A continuación introduzca nuevos datos para este cliente";

                        mensajeVent.mostrarMensaje(mensaje);

                        
                        mensajeVent.mostrarMensaje("La identificación no puede ser modificada, indique resto de datos");

                        tmpAnalizando.SetFecha(opcionesUsuario.obtenerFecha());
                        tmpAnalizando.SetCantidad(opcionesUsuario.obtenerCantidad());
                        tmpAnalizando.SetMotivo(opcionesUsuario.obtenerMotivo());
                        tmpAnalizando.SetDecoracion(opcionesUsuario.obtenerTipodecoracion());

                        mensaje = tmpAnalizando.getStringCliente();
                        mensajeVent.mostrarMensaje(mensaje);

                    } else {
                    }    

                } 

                if (clienteEncontrado == false) {
                    mensajeVent.mostrarMensaje("No se encontró el cliente con esa identificación");
                }
            } 

            
            if (opcionEligeUsuario == 3) {

                String listado = "";

                Iterator<Cliente> it2 = listaDeCliente.iterator();
                Cliente tmpAnalizando;

                while (it2.hasNext()) {           
                    tmpAnalizando = it2.next();                
                    listado = listado + tmpAnalizando.getStringCliente();
                   
                } 

                mensajeVent.mostrarMensaje(listado);

            } 
            if (opcionEligeUsuario == 4) {
                String identClienteBuscado = opcionesUsuario.obtenerIdentificacionCliente();
                boolean clienteEncontrado = false;

                Iterator<Cliente> it = listaDeCliente.iterator();
                Cliente tmpAnalizando;

                while (it.hasNext() && clienteEncontrado == false) {           

                    tmpAnalizando = it.next();               

                    if (tmpAnalizando.getIdentificacion().equals(identClienteBuscado)) {
                        clienteEncontrado = true;
                        String mensaje = tmpAnalizando.getStringCliente();
                        mensaje = mensaje + "Se procede al borrado de datos de este cliente\n\n";

                        mensajeVent.mostrarMensaje(mensaje);

                        
                        listaDeCliente.remove(tmpAnalizando);
                        clienteEncontrado = true;

                    } else {
                    }                    

                } 

                if (clienteEncontrado == false) {
                    mensajeVent.mostrarMensaje("No se encontró el cliente con esa identificación");
                }

            } 
            if (opcionEligeUsuario == 5) {
                String identClienteBuscado = opcionesUsuario.obtenerFecha();
                boolean clienteEncontrado = false;

                Iterator<Cliente> it = listaDeCliente.iterator();
                Cliente tmpAnalizando;

                while (it.hasNext()) {           

                    tmpAnalizando = it.next();                

                    if (tmpAnalizando.getFecha().equals(identClienteBuscado)) {
                        clienteEncontrado = true;
                        String mensaje = tmpAnalizando.getBuscador();
                      
                        mensajeVent.mostrarMensaje(mensaje);
                        

                    } else {
                    }

                }
                if (clienteEncontrado == false) {
                    mensajeVent.mostrarMensaje("No se encontró reserva en esta fecha");
                }

            }

        }
        opcionesUsuario.cerrarPrograma();
    }

} //Cierra main
```

Como debo agrego el código para que me genere un ID único por reserva registrada???

Comment: Hmm deja ver si entiendo, para ti la opcion 1 que es "Insertar Cliente" es lo mismo que crear una nueva reserva?

Comment: Si claro correcto, lo que deseo es que al registrarlo me genere un ID unico, pero que este ID no se cambie quede como valor fijo ya sea para mostrar o editarlo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso del UUID, ejemplo

```
String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
System.out.println(uniqueID);
```

Puedes poner ese UUID en la parte donde creas tu objeto Cliente

```
Cliente tmpCliente = new Cliente();

tmpCliente.SetIdentificacion(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
tmpCliente.SetNombre(opcionesUsuario.obtenerNombreCliente());
tmpCliente.SetEmail(opcionesUsuario.obtenerEmailCliente());
....
```

Claramente depende de la logica que quieras implementar porque en un parte del coddigo le pides al usuario que el genere su propio identificador y eso no tiene mucho sentido.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que el numero de identificación es el numero de cedula ciudadanía que se conoce en mi pais. Lo que busco es crear un ID de reserva. Este me sirvió te lo agradezco muchísimo. Como realizaría uno mas corto a futuro. Este lo estaba tratando de hacer pero al mostrar me lo cambiaba